# How to set up environment variables in react native

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, expo

I'm making a react native app that makes a request to my server hosted on heroku.

Should I be hiding the URL of my server and if so how can I add an environment variable to a react native project?

I have made a `.env` file and then have done this:

```
console.log(process.env.URL)
```

Which is returning undefined - I am also using expo if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Expo, there is an easy way to create environment variables.

In your `app.json` file

```json
{
 "expo": {
   "extra": {
     "URL": "https://..."        
   }
 }
}
```

After that, you will need to install the `expo-constant` package.

```
expo install expo-constants
```

And, to get the info in your app:

```js
import Constants from "expo-constants";

console.log(Constants.manifest.extra.URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

One library that I like to use that works for bare react native and expo is [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv)

1. Install it `npm i react-native-dotenv`
2. Add a `.env` file with your variables

```
MY_ENV_VARIABLE=SECRET_PASSWORD
```

3. Add the babel plugin to `.babelrc` file.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv"]
  ]
}
```

4. Import and use it

```
import { MY_ENV_VARIABLE } from "react-native-dotenv";

function doSomething() {
  console.log(MY_ENV_VARIABLE);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it didnt work, Seems like the developer stopped making updates to it?

Comment: @NotaGuruDotCom maintainer of react-native-dotenv. The library has transferred ownership. Updates are actively being done!